# Laravel 8: Array to string conversion on view

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-8

**UPDATE #1:**

I fixed my typo:

```
<form action="{{ route('articles.destroy'  , ['article' => $article->id]) }}" method="post">
```

But now I get this error message:

> **Illuminate\Routing\Exceptions\UrlGenerationException** Missing required
> parameters for [Route: articles.edit] [URI:
> admin/articles/{article}/edit]

Here is my `web.php`:

```
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function(){
  Route::get('/panel', [PanelController::class, 'index']);
  Route::resource('/articles', ArticleController::class);
});
```

---

I have a blade which contains a form:

```
<form action="{{ route('articles.destroy' . ['id' => $article->id]) }}" method="POST">
    {{ method_field('delete') }}
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-xs">
       <a href="{{ route('$articles.edit' . ['id' => $article->id]) }}" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">حدف</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

But when I go to this blade, it says:

> **ErrorException**
> Array to string conversion (View: F:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\resources\views\website\backend\articles\index.blade.php)

And it is referring to this line:

```
<form action="{{ route('articles.destroy' . ['id' => $article->id]) }}" method="POST">
```

I don't know why I get this error, so if you know why do I get this error, please let me know...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because you need to use `,` and not `.`

Comment: Just in case you couldn't find it: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#generating-urls-to-named-routes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
route('articles.destroy' . ['id' => $article->id])
```

the `.` is for string concatenation. You want `,`, to separate the arguments:

```
route('articles.destroy', ['id' => $article->id])
```

You also will need to match the route parameter name with the key you are passing in the array:

```
route('articles.destroy', ['article' => $article->id])
//          admin/articles/{article}
```

This assumes `$article->id` doesn't return `null`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but now I get `Missing required parameters for [Route: articles.destroy] [URI: admin/articles/{article}]`

Comment: I just updated my question about my routes. I don't know where to include `['article' => $article->id]`. Would you please help me...

Comment: it is the same array you are already passing to `route` as the second argument, just change the key from `id` to `article` so it matches the route parameter you are trying to replace

Comment: Oops, I got what you mean, and I replaced it, but the error still remains. I added my update, please help me with that!

Comment: you have to make the same change to the edit link you are creating ... its the same exact problem

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
<form action="{{ route('articles.destroy' . ['id' => $article->id]) }}" method="POST">
```

to this:

```
<form action="{{ route('articles.destroy' , ['id' => $article->id]) }}" method="POST">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but now I get `Missing required parameters for [Route: articles.destroy] [URI: admin/articles/{article}]`

Comment: your parameter name in web.php should be same as in your form
wheter both id or both article